# Any advice on reducing $(x + 1.07142)e^{-14x} = 33\times 10^{-10}$

Tags: linear-algebra, transcendental-equations

I am working on a research project and came unstuck when I got to this point. I am generating a numerical solution for some variable $x$ but cannot seem to figure out how to reduce the expression below.
The equation is

$$(x + 1.07142)e^{-14x} = 33\times 10^{-10}$$

I know the result ($x = 1.4615$..), but cant seem to figure out the solution to get that result. Any suggestions on how to go about this will be deeply appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The solution cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.  You can express it using the Lambert W function.  There are very many questions/answers if you search Lambert W.

Answer (score 2):

There are many one dimensional root finding algorithms and any numerical analysis text will discuss them.  I like the discussion in [Numerical Recipes](http://numerical.recipes/) with obsolete versions free on line.  Once you note that the root is somewhere between $1$ and $2$ any of the root finders should have an easy time.  If I just have one problem to do I often look for fixed point iteration.  If you can write your equation in the form $f(x)=x$ with $f(x)$ slowly varying it will converge rapidly.  Here I would write 
$$(x + 1.07142)e^{-14x} = 33\times 10^{-10}\\
x=-\frac 1{14}\ln\left(\frac{33\times 10^{-10}}{x + 1.07142}\right)$$
start with $x_0=1.5$ and iterate to convergence.  Writing this in a spreadsheet is easy with copy down for the iteration.  It converges to machine accuracy in six iterations.

Comment: Wow perfect.I tried using Newton's method but the extra $1.07142$ term absolutely put me off. Will try your method soon as i get home. Thank you!

Comment: Newton's should work fine.  You just need $\frac d{dx} (x + 1.07142)e^{-14x}=-14((x + 1.07142)e^{-14x})+e^{-14x}$ from the product rule.  I  find it easier to use fixed point than take the derivative because it looks so much like the problem as stated.  When you are using copy down a few extra iterations don't cost much.  If you were doing millions of these problems the faster compute time of Newton might pay off.

Answer (score 2):

As mathematician commented, the solution of equation $$(a+x) e^{-b x}=c$$ can be expressed in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) (which is not an elementary function).

Its expression is $$x=-a-\frac{1}{b}\,W\left(-b\, c\, e^{-a\, b}\right)$$ Tha Wikipedia page shows on many examples the manipulations to be done.

Applied to your case, this would give for the negative root $$x_1=-1.07142-\frac 1{14} W(-1.41344\times 10^{-14})$$ and for the positive root $$x_2=-1.07142-\frac 1{14} W(-1,-1.41344\times 10^{-14})$$ The Wikipedia page gives series expansion for the evaluation of these. For the first one, since $W(\epsilon)\approx \epsilon$, then $x_1\approx -1.07142$.

For the second one, it is slightly more complex but you can use

$$W(-1,x)={L_1}-{L_2}+\frac{{L_2}}{{L_1}}+\frac{({L_2}-2) {L_2}}{2
   {L_1}^2}+\cdots$$ where $L_1=\log(-x)$ and $L_2=\log(-L_1)$. Here $L_1=-31.8902$, $L_2=3.4623$ and then $W(-1,-1.41344\times 10^{-14})\approx -35.4585$. This makes as a result $x_2\approx 1.46133$.

As Ross Millikan answered and commented, Newton method would do a great job. Starting using $x_0=1.5$, the successive iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.500000000 \\
 1 & 1.449123485 \\
 2 & 1.460372939 \\
 3 & 1.461325908 \\
 4 & 1.461332134 
 \end{array}
\right)$$
 It could have been faster writing the equation as $$\log(x + 1.07142)-14x = \log(33\times 10^{-10})$$
Starting using $x_0=1.5$, the successive iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.500000000 \\
 1 & 1.461340525 \\
 2 & 1.461332134
\end{array}
\right)$$
Sooner or later, you will learn that any equation which can write or rewrite $$A+Bx+C\log(D+Ex)=0$$ has real and/or complex solution(s) in terms of Lambert function .

Answer (score 1):

There are two roots for
$$
 f(x) = \left( x+1.07142)e^{−14x}-33×10^{−10} \right),
$$
$$
x_{1} = -1.07142, \quad x_{2} = 1.461332134293102.
$$
There is no closed form solution.

The plot below of 
$$
\log f(x)
$$
shows the location of these roots. Outside the interval bounded by the roots the value of the function is negative, and the logarithm is complex

[image: Real]

Comment: Thank you for your comment but is there a specific reason you took the logarithm of the square of the function?

Comment: @DUniQue : thanks for the nudge. Squaring the function value produces a positive function for the logarithm. But leaving out those regions produces a better visual.